# ASP.NET Core 6 MVC : having overflow problems with header

Tags: c#, html, css, asp.net-core-mvc, .net-6.0

It's a standard VS2022 ASP.NET Core 6 MVC project with one controller added using an EF6 model. The views (`Index.cshtml`, etc) are all generated by the "Add Controller" scaffolding. The layout (`.cshtml/css`) is generated when creating the project.

I added a gradient style to the layout (only change) to make it easier to see the edge of the header. I would imagine that this is a common problem which I have searched for finding numerous fixes for various overflow problems, none of which worked in my case.

The interesting thing is that it only displays whitespace when using the horizontal scrollbar. When resizing the browser (window) it works fine. There is no whitespace.

I can provide code examples but this is literally code generated by VS2022 so I'm hoping it is a common issue.

Here is a screen shot:

[image]

Comment: `one controller added using an EF6 model` could you pls let us know how you add the controller with EF 6 model? I'm sorry but I really don't know how to reproduce your issue.

Comment: The key is that the body is wider than the display width thus requiring scroll bars. It's a vanilla ASP.Net MVC app so I'd expect other to have run across this esoteric issue. I've seen it in production apps and seems to be an artifact of bootstrap. It's just that the ASP.Net scaffolding generates the view code.

Comment: sorry, but to be honest I never met such kind of issue, nor to reproduce the issue and troubleshoot it...